# Invalid column reference in hive

Tags: sql, hive

When I run the below query, I get the error "Invalid column reference: cnt". Any suggestions would be great !!

```
     select count(customer) as cnt from (
         select customer, concat(visid, lowid), count(name) 
      from  tab1 where date_time between '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-31 23:59:59' and name in ('payment: Complete', 'check: Complete')
         group by evar71, concat(visid, lowid)) t1
      where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think hive prefers aliases in the `group by`.  In addition, several column aliases are not correct:

```
select count(customer) as cnt
from (select customer, concat(visid, lowid) as ids, count(name) as cc
      from tab1
      where date_time >= '2017-05-01' and date_time < '2017-06-01' and
            name in ('payment: Complete', 'check: Complete')
      group by customer, ids
     ) t1
where cc > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks !! Still it throws invalid column reference 'cnt'.

Comment: @user3447653 . . . It should not.  `cnt` is defined in the subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff cnt is defined in the subquery and redefined in the upper query

Comment: @leftjoin . . . Bad practice, but it makes no difference to the query.  The `cnt` in the `where` clause (which I have changed) should refer to the subquery version not the alias in the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it.

```
select count(customer) as cnt from (
         select customer, concat(visid, lowid), count(name) 
      from  tab1 where date_time between '2017-05-01 00:00:00' and '2017-05-31 23:59:59' and name in ('payment: Complete', 'check: Complete')
         group by evar71, concat(visid, lowid)) t1
    having count(customer)  > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` filter applied before aggregation
that is why `where cnt > 1` does not work. There is `HAVING` keyword which introduces a condition on aggregations, it works as filter after aggregation.

```
select count(customer) cnt
...
where rows_filter_condition_here --before aggregation
having count(customer) > 1       --aggregation results filter
order by cnt desc                --this works after aggregation
```